# Simplifying a polynomial expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, approximation-theory

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients. Is there a more elegant (concise) form of the expression 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}P(x+\lambda_i)\prod_{j=1, \\ \ \\ j\neq i}^{n+1} (\lambda_i-\lambda_j)^{-1}$$
where $\lambda_1<\lambda_2<...<\lambda_{n+1}$ are arbitrary reals?

Comment: Have you tried, working out some of the first few terms ?

Comment: @New_to_this: I have tried to compute this for monomials $x^n$ but it did not get me very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prove below that whenever $P$ is a polynomial of
degree $\leq n$, your expression is simply $a_n$, the coefficient of degree $n$ in $P$.

The  polynomial 
$$
Q=P(x+T)-a_n(T-\lambda_1) \ldots (T-\lambda_n) \tag{1}
$$

has degree $ \leq n-1$ in $T$. By [partial fraction expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition), we can write

$$
\frac{Q(T)}{(T-\lambda_1)\ldots (T-\lambda_{n})}=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{b_i}{T-\lambda_i} \tag{2}
$$

where the $b_i$ are constants. In other words,

$$
\frac{P(x+T)}{(T-\lambda_1)\ldots (T-\lambda_{n})}=
a_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{b_i}{T-\lambda_i} \tag{3}
$$

A well-known trick to compute the $b_i$ is to multiply 
both sides of (3) by $(T-\lambda_i)$ and then evaluate at $T=\lambda_i$, which yields

$$
b_i=\frac{P(x+\lambda_i)}{\prod_{j\neq i}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)} \tag{4}
$$

Injecting (4) into (3), and evaluating at $T={\lambda}_{n+1}$ finishes the proof.